# how to get the console working with Doctrine and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm, console, doctrine, codeigniter-2

I've been following this great tutorial :
http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/

and at some point, you're supposed to create a doctrine-cli.php file in my app' application folder with the following code to execute Doctrine's commands from the command line:

My Doctrine repository is in /back-meetmyfriend/application/libraries/Doctrine and the Doctrine.php in libraries.

However, I can't get the console working on W7/WAMP:

I've followed step by step the tuts and my repo is
 E:\Programmes\wamp\www\back-meetmyfriend\application
and in the git Bash console when in /e/Programmes/wamp/www/back-meetmyfriend/application i type down $ php doctrine-cli.php
I'm having a PHP Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelpserSet not found

Is there something wrong with my APPPATH ? how should I configure it ?

Thanks

Comment: that tutorial is more then 2 years old. Everyone uses composer now which resolves dependencies like that symfony component.

Comment: thanks man, I've been using it with S2 but I didn't know it works with CI as well.

Comment: Check this topic: [Fatal error HelperSet not found when setting up Doctrine Console (with CodeIgniter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897589/fatal-error-helperset-not-found-when-setting-up-doctrine-console-with-codeignit/30240122#30240122)