# Fatal error HelperSet not found when setting up Doctrine Console (with CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got a problem setting up Doctrine with CodeIgniter. When running the following error is coming up:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CodeIgniter-2.2.1/application/doctrine.php on line 21
```

The folder structure looks like this

```
/application/
/application/doctrine.php
/application/libraries/
/application/libraries/Doctrine/
/application/libraries/Doctrine/Common
/application/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL
/application/libraries/Doctrine/ORM
/application/libraries/Doctrine/Symfony
/application/libraries/Doctrine/Doctrine.php
/application/libraries/Doctrine/index.html
```

This is the line 21

```
$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

Cannot find out what is the problem..

Followed this tutorial: http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2/

update This is my doctrine.php in the application folder

```
<?php

define('APPPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
define('BASEPATH', APPPATH . '/../system/');
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

chdir(APPPATH);

require __DIR__ . '/libraries/Doctrine.php';

foreach ($GLOBALS as $helperSetCandidate) {
    if ($helperSetCandidate instanceof \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet) {
        $helperSet = $helperSetCandidate;
        break;
    }
}

$doctrine = new Doctrine;
$em = $doctrine->em;

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));

\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run($helperSet);
```

Comment: **2. Create the file application/libraries/Doctrine.php.** You put the file directly into APPATH. You named it with lower case, follow instructions strictly. On link you have provided, file should called Doctrine.php.

Comment: You must show the file `doctrine.php` in full. The helperset class is not getting loaded. You may have to register it with the class loader

Comment: @Phillip Not loaded because file that is calling it is not in place.

Comment: @Tpojka He has both of those files, although `Doctrine.php` needs to be taken out of the `Doctrine folder`

Comment: Check again my first comment, than go to [link](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2/) provided, and see those three steps. No file in `application` folder nor should be in any CI application.

Comment: `application/doctrine.php` is for the CLI, `applications/libraries/Doctrine.php` is for the library wrapper. **both** are required.

Comment: Yes but thats for the 'normal' doctrine setup, followed that part it step-by-step. The part i talked about is ' Setting up the Doctrine Console' . There they said that i have to create a doctrine.php in the application folder (with lowercase). Put the code inside it and then, when i run php application/doctrine.php i got this error...

Answer (score 2):

Just downloaded [github version](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/CodeIgniter-2-with-Doctrine-2) and without any extra settings everything [seems to be ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWGdu.png).

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. Rating answer won't hurt you. ;)

Comment: True, just created an account on Stackoverflow.. so not enough reputation  yet... :p

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `HelperSet.php` file exists in  `Doctrine/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper` directory, and add these lines to `Doctrine.php` in `libraries` directory (you have to register Symfony classes):

```
$symfonyClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Symfony',  APPPATH.'your_path_to/Doctrine');
$symfonyClassLoader->register();
```

[This GitHub repository](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/CodeIgniter-2-with-Doctrine-2) is for CodeIgniter 2, don't use it.
Try [this tutorial](http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/), it works fine for me, even for CI 3.